# How to run a command to before starting systemctl service

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, systemd, services

I am creating a `systemctl` service for a python script which needs `openvino` environment initialized. Before running the python script, we have to initialize the `openvino` environment and have to run the python script from the same terminal in order to run it otherwise it will throw error. I have created below service for this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch application

[Service]
User=john
WorkingDirectory=/home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStartPre=/opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/john/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython/rtsp_ttfr.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now as per my understanding, I am using `ExecStartPre` to initialize the openvino environment. OpenVino environment can not be initialized with root user and because we normally run systemctl service using root and this is why the python script is giving errors related to environment not initialized.

Is there any way we can mention everything to be run under john user. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: after understanding the actual issue**

Based on the OpenVINO documentation: [Install Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit for Linux](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html#set-the-environment-variables).

Create a script which contains both commands:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
## /yourscript.sh
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
/usr/bin/python3 /home/john/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython
```

Then call this script from your service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch application

[Service]
User=john
WorkingDirectory=/home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/yourscript.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**First version**

I'm not shure to completely understand your issue, but if you need the openvino service to be run as root and the ExecStartPre only to run as John, you can probably create a shell script that logs in as John and launched from ExecStartPre:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
## /yourscript.sh
su -l john -c '/opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh' -
```

**Note**: don't forget the last dash at the end which will set the John environment variables.

Then add execution rights to it:

```bsh
# chmod +x /yourscript.sh
```

End to finish, here is the service file afterwards:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch application

[Service]
## removed the user param
WorkingDirectory=/home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStartPre=/yourscript.sh ## changed the script to yourscript.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/john/Documents/ThingTraxVisionPython/rtsp_ttfr.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea of creating a shell script. I have question. When I start my service, I will have to use `sudo systemctl start <service-name>`. This include `sudo` so don't you think, its going to run everything under root user. I have tried your solution andgetting same error

Comment: it's uncorrelated, because systemd has its own daemon which runs as root (did not verify but highly likely). But please update your post and share the exact error log you have, it's hard to reason about it otherwise. Maybe your error is not related to that. Based on the installation instructions of openvino (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html#set-the-environment-variables), it's not enough to run the script, you need to make it run in the same bash instance as the startup script itself

Comment: You should try to create a script that launches both the setupvars.sh and rtsp_ttfr.py and replace your ExecStart with this script. Therefore, the env variables will be set when rtsp_ttfr.py will be called (See my edit)

Comment: Let me try few of the solutions you suggested and will update you

Comment: @SAndrew did it work for you in the end ?

Comment: yes it works. So now I have script which initialize the environment and also starts the python code. I have systemd service which simply calls the bash script. If I start the service, I can see the opencv window and the code working fine. The only issue currently I am facing is that its not starting at system boot even after doing `sudo systemctl enable <service>`.

Comment: My planning is to add `sleep 60` in bash script so that it will delay the python code execution at system boot up

Comment: If you need to make it start after the computer has started, you should consider putting your script in the ~/.xprofile file which is loaded when the X server is started. Consider specifying this question as answered if you think it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As systemctl run as root you can use sudo to switch to another user without password prompt. Example:

```
root@leo-pc:~# sudo -u leonid bash
leonid@leo-pc:~$
```